# Problema de Tipo array de n numeros pero el programa termina cuando el usuario no quiera escribir más números

Tags: java, array

Desarrollar un programa que solicite leer n números y mostrarlos en el mismo orden introducido. Que el programa termine cuando el usuario no quiera escribir más números.
En el ejercicio creo que quiere decir que el programa termina cuando el usuario digite cualquier cosa menos un numero.
Hay alguna forma de hacerlo? Solo se que se desarrolla con array.
Lo que yo he intentado es hacer lo siguiente:
Pero no se que ponerle al numero de términos del array ni tampoco se como hacer para el programa termine.

```
package javaapplication66;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication66 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sn=new Scanner(System.in); 

         for( int i=0;i>0;i++){
             double t[]=new double[];           
       System.out.println("Digite numero");
       t[i]=sn.nextDouble();
      
       }        
  }                  
 }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si entendí bien tu pregunta pero intentaré ayudarte.

Si quieres introducir números lo harás con un for hasta n como tienes hecho pero no te acaba nunca por dos razones:

1.- El bucle que implementas es infinito por la razón 2  de tu condición del for`i>0` y siempre será mayor a 0 en tu bucle, por eso nunca acaba.

2.-Y de la manera que lo tienes implementado, en cada iteración estas creando una array distinta.

Mira mi código:

```
public static void main(){
boolean sigue=true;  //para indicar si acabo o no.
double t[]=new double[]; //declaro mi array fuera del bucle.

for(int i=0;i<n && sigue;i++){
System.out.println("Introduce un número:");
int numeroLeido=sc.nextDouble();
if(numeroLeido== -1) sigue = false; //saldremos del bucle.
else t[i]=numeroLeido; //sino, introducimos el valor numeroLeido a nuestraArray.
} //acaba el for

//leemos el contenido de nuestra Array
for(int i=0;i<t.length;i++){
System.out.println(t[i]);
}
```

En mi código si introduces -1 se parará. Espero que te haya servido y lo hayas entendido.